# How to properly introduce notation in a mathematical article?

Tags: article-writing

The main result I am currently trying to publish is the proof of a classical result in optimization, but with weaker hypotheses. In the introduction of my draft, I intend to explain why this classical result is relevant and why its current hypotheses are too strong, but it is not possible to do that with English words and I need quite a lot of mathematical terms and notation. So my question is:

> Where do I put sentences like "*we denote by $X$ the idea $Y$*" and "*we say $X$ satisfies the property $Y$ when $Z$ happens*" without losing the readers' attention?

I wrote all the notations I need, in the most organized way I could, and it fills an entire page with font size 10 and narrow margins. It looks tiresome and I am afraid people give up on reading it if this is the first thing they see on the paper, but I cannot explain anything without it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a difficult question that ponders many members of this site. For a precise answer it is formulated in a too general way. – Do your best, and let one or two friends in your department read it. To go over an "introduction" is a service that any mathematician colleague should render.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I am surely going to do that, but since I know they might be very busy right now with online classes, I am saving that as a last resource. What motivated me to ask it in M.SE. is that I thought this was a common issue in pure mathematics. It is not that common in optimization since we usually motivate our results by mentioning applications. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writhing math is more art than science, but as a general rule, you want to put definitions and notations as close to their use as is reasonably possible. This generally helps in at least two situations your reader might find themselves in:

**The reader is skimming and sees notation they don't recognize.** It's reasonable to expect that they will first look in the immediate vicinity of where it was used - perhaps tracing backwards to its first use - to look for an explanation. If you put your definition right before the first use, they will probably find it.

**The reader is reading from start to end and doesn't understand a definition's purpose.** Conversely to the previous point, this reader will be well-served by having the notation be *used* right after it is introduced. In the best-case scenario, by the time you are defining anything in a paper, an attentive reader will already see why we want to make that definition and will therefore easily integrate the new notation into their understanding of the article.

Note that this advice precludes putting a huge chunk of prose whose only purpose is to introduce definitions and notation - such a block will be difficult for any reader to make use of. If you have a lot of notation or your article is very long (e.g. it is actually a book), you could include an alphabetized reference for notation that just lists symbols and what they mean (but this should be thought of as a table *not* as prose).

In practical advice, where you put definitions will depend on their purpose. If your proof centers around defining some novel object or collection of objects, you would want to give an informal big picture outline of your proof near the start of the article and then devote a chunk of text to formalizing that big picture - wherein you will introduce definitions. If a definition is used to kick off a series of lemmas, define it right before those lemmas and right after you give an outline of why it makes sense to define. If it's just a little trick to get you through a single lemma, define it in the body of that lemma.

Basically, you can ask yourself questions to decide where to put each definitions: Do you need it to sketch the broad outline of the proof? Define it at the start where you provide such an outline. Does it appear as a technical detail in several proofs? Define it before the first proof that needs it. etc.

Comment: Thank you! But my problem is that the only definition I really need is the end of a long chain of definitions. I want the paper to be as short as possible and you gave me an idea. I think I can explain things better in a particular case that requires less notation.

Comment: @Koto Using a particular case sounds like a wise idea. I might also add the alternative of treating the final definition you want as a goal in the same way you'd treat a theorem as a goal - you first sketch why you want it (e.g. "We want an object that captures some intuitive quality of X") and then informally sketch how you'll get there - and then start defining things, treating definitions like equations which are explained in prose and situated in the larger picture - this takes some thought to write and leads to a larger section than just definitions alone, but is more easily read.